# Azure DevOps - calling another pipeline using parameters

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a pipeline "app" with build stage and deploy stage. Deploy stage is further broken down into env - dev, stg, prod.

We have another pipeline "assets" which we run manually passing the env parameter - dev, stg, prod.

I need to automate it by calling assets pipeline 3 times from app pipeline when deploy job runs for dev, stg and prod.

I can trigger assets pipeline from app pipeline but i cannot trigger using parameters from app pipeline.

Has someone done this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After each deployment add a step that will run the asset pipeline with an appropriately set env parameter using the [az pipelines run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/pipelines?view=azure-cli-latest#az-pipelines-run) command.

```
- bash: |
    az pipelines run --id $(AssetPipelineDefinitionId) --parameters "env=Dev"
  displayName: 'Trigger AssetPipeline with env parameter'
  env:
    AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(System.AccessToken)
```

NOTES:

- in order for your pipeline to run another pipeline you need to assign the [queue builds permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/policies/permissions?view=azure-devops#set-individual-pipeline-permissions) to the ADO Project Build Service user,
- set AssetPipelineDefinitionId [variable in pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-pipeline).

Comment: Hey @fenrir, can we do this with azure subscription instead of pat ?